# Calculating output impedance of Vbe multiplier

Tags: analog, circuit-analysis, bjt

I am trying to calculate the output impedance of the following Vbe multiplier,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdlv6p.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have calculated the Vout = 4.2V and now I am trying to calculate the output impedance, so in order to do this I tried to do it by AC analysis. So got the below figure,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBUZWf.png)</sup>

So now I am not sure how to process further, I know re//R1 and re = 1 / (40 * Ic) but after this how do I proceed further?

Comment: You need to take the feedback in this circuit into account.  The feedback lowers the apparent output impedance.  You will also have to model the B-E junction and the gain of the transistor, which can have considerable variation from part to part.  Start at the unloaded operating point, add a small load, trace thru all that happens as a result of that to eventually find the output voltage change, then compute impedance from that.  Not trivial.

Comment: Looking at this a little more, I think it will be easier to perturb the unloaded case with a small output voltage change, then compute the resulting output current change.  Output impedance will be a strong function of 1/gain.  If you approximate gain as infinite, then output impedance will be 0.

Comment: This problem is a good indication of why you should consider a transistor as voltage controlled. ;-)

Comment: @Spehro: I think you mean NOT consider a transistor as voltage controlled.

Comment: @Spehro: Yes - we not only "should" but we "must" because this corresponds to the physical reality.

Comment: I'm not sure about the circuit model.  Except for the short it's a current source into mostly Re.  I was going to guess n times Re. (Re= 25mV/Ic ~4 ohms or so.) and n is the multiplying factor.

Comment: I am the teacher who gave this original exercise in an exam :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since we have seen some different approaches to arrive at the (correct) solution, here comes my version:

1.) From feeback theory we know that **r,out=r,open/(1-LG)**
    (with r,open: output resistance without feedback; LG=Loop gain).

2,) For calculation of r,open and LG we open the feedback loop at a point which does not require a load mirror (no loading errors due to opening): Such a node is at the base because r,be may be assumed to be infinite (ib=0 because of beta infinite).

3.) From simple inspection: **r,open=R1+R2  and LG=-gm*(R1+R2)*R2/(R1+R2)=-gm*R2.**

4.) Inserting into the expression under 1) gives **r,out=(R1+R2)/(1+gm*R2).**

5.) Setting gm=Ic/Vt=0.235 A/V we have **r,out=25.4 ohms**.

Comment: Simulation results for real model 2N3904 (however, with buffer between voltage divider and base node because of Ib=0): 26.4 ohms. Without buffer (finite beta): 55.5 ohms.

Answer (score 1):

The small-signal circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS698v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transconductance gm = \$\frac{Ic}{Vt} \approx \frac{6.1mA}{26mV} \approx 0.235\Omega^{-1}\$

\$ R_{\pi} = \beta \cdot  \frac{Vt}{Ic} = \infty \$

\$ Ro = \frac{(Va+ Vce)}{Ic}\$, but since we're not given Va (and it's usually something like 100V), assume \$\infty \$

So for a delta voltage in we have an increase in current from the source
of \$\frac{gm}{6}\$, so it looks like a resistance of 25.5 ohms, and
it's in parallel with R1 + R2, so about 25.4 ohms (in parallel with Ro if you like, but that won't make any significant difference).

Comment: You should note that this is for a more realistic model of the transistor than the OP specified.  A transistor with a fixed Vbe of 700 mV and infinite gain would result in 0 output impedance of the circuit.

Comment: @OlinLathrop  I believe the Vbe = 0.7V was provided to allow a straightforward calculation of the large-signal operating point. Once you have that, no other parameters are necessary (assuming room temperature). The point of this exercise, as I see it, is for the student to determine the operating point and then find the output impedance from the small signal model. That's why he's starting off with controlled sources in there. That's my take anyhow.

Comment: @Spehro: I can confirm your above result (app. 25 ohms). It corresponds with my calculations - based on the approach "open-loop output resistance divided by (1+loop gain)".

Comment: Oh - I forgot to write down the result (as a formula): r,out=(R1+R2)/(1+gm*R2). This assumes ib=0 (rbe infinite) and ro infinite (the BJT`s internal output resistance).

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I interpret the 700mV as the DC base-emitter voltage, not the total (DC plus small-signal) base-emitter voltage.

Answer (score 1):

We can almost write the answer by inspection since \$r_o\$ and \$\beta\$ are specified as 'infinite'.

With \$\beta =\infty\$, there is no small-signal base current, so the small-signal base-emitter voltage is simply

$$v_{be} = v_{out}\frac{R_1}{R_1 + R_2} = \frac{v_{out}}{6}$$

The small-signal collector current is thus

$$i_c = g_m \cdot v_{be} = \frac{g_m \cdot v_{out}}{6}$$

and small-signal current through the voltage divider is

$$i_R = \frac{v_{out}}{6k\Omega}$$

Putting this together, the small-signal output resistance is

$$r_{out}=\frac{6}{g_m}||6k\Omega \approx \frac{6}{g_m}$$

---

> how is r0 infinite

if \$r_o\$ or the Early voltage \$V_A\$ isn't specified, it is typically assumed to be infinite.

However, including a finite \$r_o\$ in this case, since the emitter is grounded, is easy:

$$r_{out} = \frac{6}{g_m}||6k\Omega||r_o$$

But this will not change the approximate result above since the \$\frac{6}{g_m}\$ term is much smaller than the other two terms.

> and i also didn't understand how you calculated output resistance at the end, could you explain?

Conceptually, I attached a (small-signal) *test voltage source* to the output node and took the ratio of the test source voltage to the test source current.

$$r_{out} = \frac{v_{test}}{i_{test}} = \frac{v_{out}}{i_c + i_R} = \frac{v_{out}}{\frac{g_m\cdot v_{out}}{6} + \frac{v_{out}}{6k\Omega}} = \frac{1}{\frac{g_m}{6}+ \frac{1}{6k\Omega}}= \frac{6}{g_m}||6k\Omega $$

Comment: how is r0 infinite and i also didn't understand how you calculated output resistance at the end, could you explain?

Comment: @user2280164, I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks now its clear to me. Now there is one thing that is striking in my mind, it is about the value of Zout. This value 25 ohm seems to be small but is it really small. It is said that Zout must be small but how small is 25 ohm small? If not can it be further reduced by reducing the value of R1 and R2?

Comment: @user2280164. the dominant term is the \$\frac{6}{g_m}\$ term.  Doubling the DC collector current will approximately halve the output resistance.

Comment: Ic can be increased by increasing the value if R1 and R2 as this decreases the current through the resistors and thus increase the collector current.

Answer (score 0):

With your simplifying assumption of V<sub>be</sub> fixed at 700 mV and the transistor gain infinite, it can be seen from inspection that the output impedance is 0.

Here is one way to find the output impedance.  First, find the unloaded output voltage.  From the R1-R2 divider, we can see that V<sub>out</sub> must be 6x V<sub>be</sub>, which comes out to 4.2 V.  That is the output voltage at 0 output current.  Now consider what happens when that output voltage is externally perturbed a bit.  Let's say something is holding it 1 mv higher, at 4.201 V.  That R2-R1 divider is a Thevenin source that will now be 1/6 mV above 700 mV with a impedance of 833 Ω.  Since you specified that the B-E drop is fixed at 700 mV, this Thevenin source will be dumping (1/6 mV)/(833 Ω) = 200 µA thru the base.  That times your infinite gain results in infinite collector current in response to the 1 mV output voltage rise.  The dynamic output impedance is therefore (1 mV)/infinity = 0 Ω.

You can repeat the calculation above with the minimum guaranteed gain.  That will tell you the minimum guaranteed output impedance *with the assumption of the B-E drop fixed at 700 mV*.  Unfortunately, when you are looking at details like the output impedance of this circuit, that's not a good model.  For this, you should probably use the exponential diode equation for the B-E junction.  At the very least, model it as a fixed drop with a resistance in series.

There are many useful things that can be computed about transistor circuits by using a first order approximation of the B-E drop being fixed and some fixed or infinite gain, but this is not one of them.  You have to know when simplified models are appropriate and when not.

Comment: I cannot see why the output impedance should be zero (for beta approaching infinity). As can be seen, we have a finite loop gain - and this always gives a finite output resistance. Of course, the loop gain must be calculated taking Ic=f(Vbe) into account, that means: voltage control (physical truth). In this case (Ib=0 for beta infinite) we can compare the BJT with a FET - of course, with a finite output resistance.

Comment: @LvW: No, we don't have a finite loop gain. That's the point. The infinite beta makes infinite loop gain.  Follow the calculations I show and you see where we divide by beta.

Comment: What means "beta infinite"? Ic infinite for a finite Ib? No - of course, not. Instead: Ib=0 for Ic finite ! Therefore, my example with the FET. For calculating the loop gain only Vbe and gm matters!.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all suggestions and comments. With this help I have down the following calculation for my output impedance (Zout),

First changed into the Ac analysis model

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2iYst.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From this we can now calculate the following,

- Vpie= i * (R1//Rpie)
- Now, i= V/ (R2 + (R1//Rpie))

Now we can reduce the circuit as following,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgChtV.png)</sup>

Further reduce the above schematic to following,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMryBi.png)</sup>

Now, finally we will have the following schematic to calculate the Zout.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIllQO.png)</sup>

Now, Zout = (R2+ R1//Rpie)/(1+gm(R1//Rpie))

we know,

- gm = (40*Ic)= (40*6.3mA)=0.252
- Rpie = 25mV/6.3mA = 3.96 ohm

Replacing the value of gm and Rpie in Zout, we get

- Zout = (5000 + (1000//3.96))/ (1+0.252*(1000//3.96))

  = (5000+ 3.94)/ (1+0.252*3.94)

  = 5003.94/ 1.992

  = 2.51 Kohm

Vbe multiplier is suppose to have a small output impedance but as calculated above Zout is fairly big then expected, so is there any way to reduce Zout!!

Comment: I didn`t check your calculatiuon in detail - however, the result can`t be correct. Did you follow Spehro`s calculation? Output resistance must be somewhere around 25 Ohms. This value also follows from loop gain calculation.

Comment: I checked the answer from Spehro but I didn't understand how he got 25 ohm. What is the value of Va and Vce and what about Ic isn't it 6.3mA?